# Passing JSON Header and Body to subsequent InvokeHTTP Processor in ApacheNifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to build an automated flow to export profiles from a SaaS cloud platform where I have all the REST APIs. Here is what I am doing

1. Login to login API to get token (I have been able to successfully do that using InvokeHttp processor). I get the token in the response JSON as follows
   `{ "access_token" : "<some_token_value>", "links" : [ { "rel" : "self", "href" : "https://ccadmin-xxxx.oracleoutsourcing.com/ccadmin/v1/login" } ], "token_type" : "bearer", "expires_in" : 300 }`
2. I extract the token from the JSON using EvaluateJSONPath and add dynamic property "token" to map to access_token of the JSON response I got.
   The output of evaluateJsonPath is an attribute "token" which has the value of access_token from step 1.
3. Now i am preparing a BODY for the next POST call, so i use UpdateAttribute processor to define my attributes.
4. Next i convert the attributes that i define in the previous step to JSON using AttributesToJSON processor. This adds the following to the attributes path in its output

JSONAttributes
`{"mode":"standalone","filename":"profiles.json","format":"json","id":"Profiles"}`

Also the token from step 1 still flows as an attribute

5. Next i pass all this to my 2nd InvokeHttp processor to call the bulk export.
   Now, I want to pass this token as the Header and also pass the JSON body to the  Invoke HTTP processor. So i just make the following change. Add a dynamic attribute to the InvokeHTTP called "Authorization" and pass value as Bearer ${token} and i believe the body will automatically be taken from the attributes from previous processor.

But the call fails. Is there anything i am missing. I have tried running this through POSTMAN and everything runs fine there.

[Nifi Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuAPV.png)

[Input to 2nd InvokeHttp Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpPef.png)

[Second InvokeHttp POST processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fCWL.png)

Comment: flow & logic seems to be ok. you could try to send your second request to debugging post endpoint: https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/post_post - as a result you should  see json response with all headers and body that nifi sent to server.

Comment: what is the current response http code and message?

Comment: I am seeing the following error invokehttp.response.body
`{"errorCode":"120001","message":"Missing export processes information","status":"400"}` which doesnt make sense as this error comes if mode:standalone is missing from request body, but i see that getting passed. Here is the JSONattributes that i see `{"mode":"standalone","fileName":"profile.json","format":"json","id":"Profiles"}`

Comment: As variant - content-type is missing in request or it's wrong

Comment: i'm about content type parameter in your second request https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fCWL.png

Comment: I think i got the issue. i see all the things are flowing as attributes in the flow. The body needs to flow as content. so i  cut short the UpdateAttribute and AttributeToJSON and instead put a ReplaceText processor and put the JSON body there. And i am able to make a successful call now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the issue. i see all the things are flowing as attributes in the flow. The body needs to flow as content. so i cut short the UpdateAttribute and AttributeToJSON and instead put a ReplaceText processor and put the JSON body there. And i am able to make a successful call now.

Comment: Hi Gurvinder, even i am facing an similar issue, could you share a template or more data on how you achieved the same? Thank you